# Synchronize two SQL Server CE 4.0 databases/ data replication

Tags: entity-framework, synchronization, sql-server-ce

How to synchronize two SQL Server CE 4.0 databases? I'm using version 4.0 because I want to use the code first approach. As it turned out SQL Server CE 4.0 does not support MS Sync framework, and SQL Server CE 3.5 supports MS Sync but does not support  full code first approach. (No Database Creation).

I would like to use at least EF database first. How can I do in this situation? Abandon the code first and switch to SQL Server CE 3.5? Use SQLite or other compact database like ms access. Maybe write my own synchronization using a TimeStamp for each row.

A similar question [Using MS Sync Framework to synchronize two SQL CE Dbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581110/using-ms-sync-framework-to-synchronize-two-sql-ce-dbs)

Answer (score 1):

You can make Sync Framework work with SQL CE 4. It's unsupported though.

have a look at
:[Sync Framework and SQL Compact 4 (Yes, You Can!)](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/)